# How do I clear old installation files?

Tags: 11.10, installation, uninstall

I recently updated to 11.10 with a few challenges.

It seems I have a few left over files from the previous installation. Because when booting the system, i am given options to choose which version of Ubuntu I want to boot up.

There is not any obvious difference between the separate options i am given.

How do I clear the files/options I do not need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you mean all the different older Kernels you still have listed in grub.

You can search them using the Synaptic Package Manager:

search for `linux-image` and you will get a list of installed kernels.

Before uninstalling the not needed ones, first open a terminal and invoke:

```
uname -r
```

This will give you an output stating the currently running kernel. Do not remove this linux-header-packet!!!

Further I suggest not to remove kernels with a higher version number than the one you are currently using and to keep at least a second kernel for the case.

Please be careful what you are doing, you could break your system if you are not careful.